# How to create functions base on config in javascript class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I can defined `readFoo` in `Foo` class:

```
var myFormat = 'foo'

class Foo {
  [ "read" + ((format) => format)(myFormat) ]() {
    return 123;
  }
}
```

is there any way how to define function base on config like:

```
var config = ['foo1', 'foo2']
class Foo {
  config.map((name) => {
    [ "read" + ((format) => format)(name) ]() {
      return 123;
    }
  }
}
```

Will create functions `readFoo1` and `readFoo2`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Comment: What exactly is the use case? Why does your class have multiple methods that are so similar to each other that you can define them in a loop?

Comment: ...Instead, it is almost surely better to have a single method, that takes `format` as its argument, and acts based on that.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the array and assign to the prototype afterwards:

```js
var config = ['foo1', 'foo2']
class Foo {}
for (const name of config) {
  Foo.prototype["read" + name] = function() {
    return 123;
  };
}


const f = new Foo();
console.log(f.readfoo1());
```

Comment: Is there any way how to add some `decorator` over this dynamic function?

Comment: Decorators are still only stage 2, they're not ready for use yet, in vanilla JS at least